# How to convert custom url wordpress to friendly url

Tags: php, wordpress

I have one problem, Once page in WordPress need a parameter in `$_GET`.
I got URL,

```
example: homepage.com/something/?param1=someString,
```

I would like to get `homepage.com/something/someString`  <--- someString would like to get in table `$_GET`. I tried by htaccess but it's not working.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^something/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/something/([a-z]+)/?$ /something/?param1=$1 [L]
```

Additional when I tried `homepage.com/something/someInteger`  It's going to the correct page, "something" but when I tried homepage.com/something/someString <---

> It's going to 404 page, why?

Somebody any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: See this page. I’ve used this in the past. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/

Comment: I used add_rewrite_rule and It's working! Remember don't forget flush the rules in Settings in Panel Admin.